# Instantiate ArrayList with map from another ArrayList

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, types, instanceof

I have a current ArrayList of type A and I want to create a new list of all the object in this list that is of type B where B is a sub-class of A. Is there a way to do this using a map()?

```
ArrayList<B> allBs = allAs.stream().map( b -> where b instanceof B)
```

That would maybe look something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) function:

```
List<B> allBs = allAs.stream()
                     .filter(B.class::isInstance)  
                     .map(B.class::cast)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which will filter out any elements that don't match the given predicate, cast them to `B` objects, and then collect it to a new `List`.

Also note that I changed `ArrayList<B> allBs` to `List<B> allBs`, because it is good practice to [program to the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Im unable to create allBs as type B, it only works if I make the list of type A. The error I get is: Required List B, but 'collect' was inferred to R

Comment: @Hdot Sorry fixed